# Find the number of occurrences of words in an array and return an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings that have duplicate values:

`const = ['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'apple', 'pear', 'pear']`

What I would like to return is the following:

`let occurrences = [{fruit: 'apple', numberOfOccurences: 3},{fruit: 'orange', numberOfOccurences: 1}, {fruit: pear, numberOfOccurences: 2}]`

I have tried `reduce` and nested `for` loops but it is not returning the results I am expecting.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: You should add what you've tried to the question.

Comment: There are tens of answers to this exact question on stack overflow

Comment: @jamiec if you can link to one, then great as I cannot find one that suits this scenario

Comment: make a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). for all `fruit` in your array, if map does not have fruit, set fruit to 1, otherwise get fruit and set fruit to fruit + 1. after iteration has completed, create the desired output from the map.

Comment: Here is an example of what Mulan mentioned https://jsbin.com/dunoyezuho/edit?js,console

Answer (score -2):

Quite trivial with reduce

```js
const fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'apple', 'pear', 'pear'];

const stats = Object.values(fruits.reduce((acc,fruit) => {
  acc[fruit] ??= {fruit,num:0}
  acc[fruit].num++;
  return acc
},{}))
console.log(stats);
```